# Conditional column positioning using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Form that will display a simple version in some cases and a more complex version in others.  I have that part working.  But the form is 2 columns and needs to be in order.  All of the second column and parts of the first column are hidden for the simple mode.

They would like me to show the form in 2 columns, when in simple mode there are 8 fields shown and they would like it (in full screen mode) to show them in 2 columns of 4x4 but when in complex mode it will be one column with form fields and a check box list on the other.

How can I make this form work like that?
The AdvancedFilter Class Items get hidden when it is the simple version.

Summary.  Needs to always display in 2 columns in the order listed.  AdvancedFilter items will be hidden sometimes and the unhidden fields need to shift into a second column during standard width use and back to 1 for mobile use.

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">                    
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <textbox id="tb1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <textbox id="tb2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <textbox id="tb3" />
            </div>
        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <textbox id="tb4" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <textbox id="tb5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 AdvancedFilter">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select id="sel1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <Select id="sel2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 AdvancedFilter">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select id="sel3" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select id="sel4" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 AdvancedFilter">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select id="sel5" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 AdvancedFilter">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select id="sel6" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 AdvancedFilter">
            <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <select id="sel7" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 AdvancedFilter">
        <div class="col-md-3">
             <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div>
            <checkbox id="cb1" />
            </div>
            <div>
            <checkbox id="cb2" />
            </div>                  
            ...                 
            <div>
            <checkbox id="cb16" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(If it matters this is an ASP.Net MVC Razor view but I do not believe that will matter for this.)

Comment: I think it won't be possible to do what you want with just Bootstrap's CSS alone. Is a javascript/jquery solution OK?

Comment: Is it not possible to control the markup on the server-side? Can you switch between simple and advanced mode on the client-side?

Comment: @KodosJohnson yes its all done clientside now using jquery/javascript

Comment: And I would prefer not to have to go back to the server to create the page because i need to alter the display...  That kind of breaks the idea behind MVC

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

if you just want 2 columns of 4 under each other.

like:

```
O O   
O O    ordered like this
O O   
O O 



              <div class="row form-group">
                   <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <!-- add this 4 times -->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- end of add -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

And if you want 2 columns of 4 items. but 2 next to each other

like :

```
O O     O O  
                 ordered like this
O O     O O 

               <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class = "control-label col-md-3" }) />
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <textbox id="tb1" />test
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
```

Sorry for the formatting. But I tested it the O represent te items so you have two possibilities now. With this

EDIT:

I read your question again. if you want it to show in different format when on different size. add `class="col-sm-12"` or something like it. on big and medium screens it displays the thing i created. and when smaller it would just be all 8 items underneath each other

Comment: Addition to my post. you CAN do this pure bootstrap, the col tag is defined for types of how big the screen can be so it is possible to shift between layouts. you can add that to my post. just a double class like `class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"`

Comment: What you posted is right. It is possible to get autoshifting collumn layout using twitter bootstrap.

Comment: ACtually I need 3 total columns but only 2 ever displayed as columns.  When column 3 is hidden I need column 1 and 2 to be side by side.  When 3 is visible i need column 1 and 2 to be displayed verticly

Comment: I can try to look into it tomorow

Comment: So i looked in to it some further. if you want columns to actually not display and display you have to fiddle arround an awefull lot to do this. it is still posible but i will need somekind of an trigger like a button. and then its still easier to just do it with PHP or javascript or something like that

Comment: @H.Brendan  There is an advance search button that will initiate the change so that is workable.  (It is asp.net not php) but javascript solution could work.

Comment: I would recomend you to use javascript or jquerry or somethnig and ask a new question relating this problem for javascript specificly. even with the bounty noone can answer this question here and now 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Bootstrap are you using - Version 3? Just curious about that.

My understanding is that each group of columns that you want to function as a row is to be nested within a `<div class="row">` div? This could be a main part of the problem with how this is working for you.

Also, your HTML that you posted is not valid HTML, so it is not easy to experiment with - is this your ASP.net input?  Or some variation on it? There are things that are invalid as far as HTML is concerned that make it difficult to just try and set up an example to work with.

Comment: yeah its pseudo code the reality is html helpers and razor syntax.  That part all works its just the display issue I am trying to deal with.  The divs are identical to the page.

Comment: Rows in bootstrap are better thought of as clearfixes IMO. otherwise you don't get the responsive wrapping of columns. group the elements with a row when you are 100% sure that you never want them side by side.